# Singular Value decomposition of huge dimensional matrix

Tags: matrices, decomposition-theorem

i  would like to consider singular value decomposition of  such type of matrix

[image]

creation of  matrix from  small sample is not big issue, i have  ready code for this

```
function  [x ]=create_matrix(b,l)
%This Function is used to Create Hankel Type Data Matrix
%x is a given data
%l represent window size
    n = length(b);
    m = n-l+1;
    x = zeros(m,l);
    for i=1:m
        x(i,:)=b(i:i+l-1);
    end
```

but when i have huge  data , for instance  time series with sample size  of 500000 and  more, then creation of matrix  will make computer unresponsive, i have searched  in internet articles related to this topic and  found following resource

[efficient singular value decomposition](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/177007/updating-svd-decomposition-after-adding-one-new-row-to-the-matrix/179539#179539)

but problem is ,that before applying given algorithm , i should create  matriix itself,  my research is about  to create step by step approximation of SVD, instead of creation huge matrix, can i  create  small matrices in process,  calculate  svd of given matrix and  after loop operations ,  get  result as    the  svd of huge matrix?let me clarify  my question :

suppose i want create  matrix with size of  $n$ by $m$ which both $n$ and  $m$ are hug numbers, what i am  doing is choose small $p$ and  $k$ and creating matrix  $p$ by $k$, i will calculate svd of given matrix, then i will update  both $p$ and $k$ by $1$ unit and  repeat again process, can i  approximate  svd of original matrix?please help me  what to do?

Answer (score 4):

This problem of updating the singular value decomposition of a matrix upon repeatedly appending a row or a column to the matrix is discussed in [A stable and fast algorithm for updating the singular value decomposition](http://www.cs.yale.edu/publications/techreports/tr966.pdf).

Comment: i hope that i will be able to understood it or at least to write code, could you tell me please  a short summary about this process? what is general idea

Comment: it's an old method (1994), used by many since, you'll probably want to search for a ready-made code.

Comment: i think i need several days to clarify  process itself